# How to change hover color for Bootstrap lg button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to create some buttons in my header, for example this call button:

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-lg" style="font-size:2em;" href="tel:XXXX XXXX"><strong>Ph: XXXX XXXX</strong></a>
```

I have added some custom coloring to the `btn-lg` class:

```
.btn-lg {
background: #ffee38;
color: #000;
border:2px solid;}
```

This gives me what I want, except when the mouse hovers over the button the text and borders go a light blue. I would prefer a light grey when hovering.

**How can I make this change?** the blue hover must be coming from a default bootstrap class perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the pseudo-class `:hover` to your class and use the `color` property for changing the text and border color on hover like this:

```
.btn-lg:hover {
    color: lightgrey;
}
```

Here's a live version of your button:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<style>
.btn-lg {
    background: #ffee38;
    color: #000;
    border:2px solid;
}
.btn-lg:hover {
    color: lightgrey;
}
</style>

<a role="button" class="btn btn-lg" style="font-size:2em;" href="tel:XXXX XXXX"><strong>Ph: XXXX XXXX</strong></a>
```

Comment: how can I easily include the loading (active?) and visited states as well? they still go blue while the link is loading the new page, and on iphone after the link is clicked

Comment: Here are the link pseudo-classes: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp